# odoo v8 calculate salary based on working time

Tags: odoo

Please tell me how to calculate salary (for example, contract.wage) based on working time in odoo v8?
Basic salary should be based on working hours, but In Odoo if the employee works 1 hour or 100 hours, the system calculates full basic salary (contract.wage) for the employee.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify basic rule, in salary rules to compute this based on working time.

Payslip has detail about this, yo can set 160 hours with code WORK100 and set the rule (here is working):

```
<record id="hr_payroll.hr_rule_basic" model="hr.salary.rule">
  <field name="name">Salary</field>
  <field name="code">BASIC</field>
  <field name="category_id" ref="hr_payroll.BASIC"/>
  <field name="sequence" eval="10"/>
  <field name="amount_select">percentage</field>
  <field name="amount_percentage_base">worked_days.WORK100.number_of_hours * (contract.wage / 160)</field>
  <field name="amount_percentage">100.00</field>
</record>
```